# Why can the Rust compiler not optimize Option::take and an "if let" if you print the value?

Tags: rust, compiler-optimization

I bumped into the following observation:

```
pub fn xx(mut x: Option<usize>) -> usize {
    let y = x.take();
    //print!("{:?}", x);
    if let Some(x) = x {
        x
    } else {
        0
    }
}
```

This code (with `print!` being commented out) gets optimized to "nothing":

```
xorl    %eax, %eax
retq
```

Once I uncomment the `print!`, it can no longer optimize out the `if let Some(x) = x` anymore. I went ahead and expanded the macro (using `rustc +nightly --pretty=expanded -Z unstable-options main.rs`) and stripped minimized the code down to a minimal compilable example:

```
#![feature(print_internals)]
#![feature(fmt_internals)]

pub fn xx(mut x: Option<usize>) -> usize {
    let y = x.take();

    std::io::_print(
        ::std::fmt::Arguments::new_v1_formatted(
            &[""],
            &[::std::fmt::ArgumentV1::new(&x, ::std::fmt::Debug::fmt)],
            &[]
        )
    );

    if let Some(x) = x {
        x
    } else {
        0
    }
}
```

As far as I can see, we only reference `x` once, and it is a non-mutable reference, so nothing should prevent the optimizer from assuming it is `None` (since we `take()` it) and just constantly return `0` as in the first snippet.

[Here are the snippets in the Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/g/P6Tk38)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The optimizer is only allowed to make changes to the program that do not change the runtime behavior. By printing the `Option`, **you have changed the runtime behavior** and thus the optimizer is now more restricted.

By adding the print statement, you are making the *address* of the variable visible and important to the code:

```
&[::std::fmt::ArgumentV1::new(&x, ::std::fmt::Debug::fmt)],
//                            ^^
```

This means that the optimizer can no longer skip generating a memory location for the value or manipulating the value stored in it. Once you've added all the gunk about dynamic dispatch and IO, one extra `if` isn't going to add appreciable overhead.

---

Your *real* answer is going to be to go read the LLVM source code. Optimizations are non-trivial and they apply and don't apply for esoteric reasons.

Comment: "making the address of the variable visible" - this is what I suspected and feared.